# PayPal Acks Results and Error Codes - References

Tags: paypal

I'm trying to do some documentation and testing for several PayPal implementations and I'm having trouble tracking down the reference material for the various API responses.

1) For Express checkout What are the possible Ack values (I think Success, Successwithwarning, Failure)

2) For Express Checkout what are all the Error codes

3) For Express Checkout USING PAYFLOW what are all the result codes

4) For Payflow advanced and pro the Results are in the Payflow Getway Developer Guide and Reference (https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/payflowgateway_guide.pdf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Check out the NVP overview, specifically the [Common Response Fields](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/NVPAPIOverview/#id084DN080HY4), which shows the following possible values:

- Success
- SuccessWithWarning
- Failure
- FailureWithWarning

2) Check the [API Error and Warning Codes documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/errorcodes/) any time you need more details about a specific error code.

3) Check the [PayFlow Express Checkout documentation](https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/pfp_expresscheckout_pp.pdf).  Search for "Search Responses" and it'll take you to Page 45 where it lists the result codes.

4) Not sure I see a question here..??

Comment: AckCode:

SUCCESS("Success"),

FAILURE("Failure"),

WARNING("Warning"),

SUCCESSWITHWARNING("SuccessWithWarning"),

FAILUREWITHWARNING("FailureWithWarning"),

PARTIALSUCCESS("PartialSuccess"),

CUSTOMCODE("CustomCode");

Comment: but no description :(.